# How to access Synology NAS drive using API

Tags: nas, synology

I am newbie to synology. I want to access my Synology NAS drive. I followed `Synology_Download_Station_Official_API`.

I read basic Working example to get API Information:

> Step 1: Get API Information
>   In order to make API requests, you should first request SYNO.API.Info to get the SYNO.API.Auth API 
>   info for session login and SYNO.DownloadStation.Task API info for download task list.
>
> Request:
>
> http://myds.com:5000/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&my=SYNO.API.Auth,SYNO.DownloadStation.Task

I changed **myds.com:5000** with **mydomain.com:3456**

I created GET request but every time my request times out. Am i doing something wrong?

Please guide as i am using it for first time.

Comment: rajat, Did you finally manage getting your info?

Answer (score 3):

I think your request could be wrong, but this doesn't explains why it timeout...

The correct request should be:

> http://myds.com:5000/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query&query=SYNO.API.Auth,SYNO.DownloadStation.Task

You can see the correct requests in the Synology documentation at 
https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/DownloadStation/All/enu/Synology_Download_Station_Web_API.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Ty221 the correct request to send is already in the answer! The link is for more info about the request.

Comment: Link is broken :( I will update if I find a replacement link.

Comment: Does it work also through quickconnect? I tried and I only get back the HTML content